# MessageHub stops work hours ago after application start. SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have ASP NET Core web API and use SignalR. I have 3 separate hubs, and `MessageHub` one of them. Here is the code:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public MessageHub() { }

    static List<UserDetail> ConnectedUsers = new List<UserDetail>();

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;

        ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserID = userId });

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;

        UserDetail userDetail = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == id);

        if (userDetail != null)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(userDetail);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

UserDetails:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I using overrided method for connecting and disconnecting, and it works well, but the problem is that sometimes, after an hour or day, problem appears. I start get this error in logger:

```
|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler|Error when dispatching 'OnConnectedAsync' on hub. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What can be the issue? Restarting fix this problem for a while but then it comes back.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada when error arrives other new connected users cant connect to hub, all of them get this error

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada yes, for now it have small amount of traffic, but it should grow in future

Comment: something on OnConnectedAsync is null , 
and try to put await before SendAsync i think it has something to do with it

Comment: Q: What is the purpose of assigning local UserDetail CurrentUser = ? You don't use CurrentUser for any purpose inside method OnConnectedAsync(), you could remove the statement..

Comment: A safer solution is to use a database to store your connected users, instead of relying (for hours) on static memory data. Static data in an ASP.NET application could be reset, session management may be involved, assemblies can be reloaded.. Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable

Comment: You aren't accessing ConnectedUsers in a thread safe manner, multiple threads can be using it at once in your current example, so a null ref isn't too surprising.

Comment: @Brennan what are you suggesting to do for access `ConnectedUsers`

Comment: Looks like you are facing issue with app domain recycling -https://stackoverflow.com/q/17235193/3576971. Hope this gives some insight.

Comment: Use a lock, or use a concurrent collection like ConcurrentDictionary.